# Получить значение ранее объявленной переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице объявляю некие переменные, а в скрипте хочу в зависимости от выбранных радио кнопок получить значение нужно переменной:
Вот как объявляю ранее на странице:

```
<script> var v1_pr1=210000;
 var v1_pr2=225000;
 var v1_pr3=275000;
 var v1_pr4=340000;
 var v1_pr5=360000;</script>
```

Вот как пытаюсь получить, но мне отдает тупо строку сформированную)

```
$('input.volume').on('click', function() {
    var vendors_select = $('input.vendors:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс производителя
    var volume_select = $('input.volume:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс объема
    var index_price = 'v'+vendors_select+'_pr'+volume_select;
    console.log(index_price);
...
});
```

Comment: Вам не кажется, что что-то не то с кодом? Ну или, как минимум, с подходом? На мой взгляд, если бы вы привели полностью описание Вашей задачи и то как Вы её решаете, то ответы были бы для Вас более полезны. Предполагаю, что переменные у вас генерируются сервером и если это так, то почему бы не генерировать JSON, который в JS автоматически преобразуется в объект и свободно получать к нему доступ хоть по индексу, хоть по ключу, а не использовать eval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input.volume').on('click', function() {
  var vendors_select = $('input.vendors:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс производителя
  var volume_select = $('input.volume:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс объема
  var index_price = 'v' + vendors_select + '_pr' + volume_select;
  console.log(eval(index_price));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var v1_pr1 = 210000;
  var v1_pr2 = 225000;
  var v1_pr3 = 275000;
  var v1_pr4 = 340000;
  var v1_pr5 = 360000;
</script>

<input type="radio" class="vendors" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="volume" value="3">
```

**если глобальная переменная:**

```js
$('input.volume').on('click', function() {
  var vendors_select = $('input.vendors:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс производителя
  var volume_select = $('input.volume:checked').val(); // Получаем индекс объема
  var index_price = 'v' + vendors_select + '_pr' + volume_select;
  console.log(window[index_price]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var v1_pr1 = 210000;
  var v1_pr2 = 225000;
  var v1_pr3 = 275000;
  var v1_pr4 = 340000;
  var v1_pr5 = 360000;
</script>

<input type="radio" class="vendors" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="volume" value="2">
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!)))

Comment: @Batyabest, не за что, успехов

Answer (score 1):

```js
let options = {
  've1vo1': 1111, // просто как предложение - не плодить сущности
  've1vo2': 2222, // вместо создания множества переменных - один обжект
  've1vo3': 3333, // где ключ - конкатенация value двух input-ов
  've2vo1': 4444,
  've2vo2': 5555,
  've2vo3': 7777,
  've3vo1': 1212,
  've3vo2': 3434,
  've3vo3': 7565
},
  $radio = $('input[type=radio]'),
  result = '';

$radio.on('change', function () {
  let v = $(this).val();
  $radio.each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      result = result + $(this).val();
    }
  });
  if (options[result]) {
    $('#result').html(options[result]);
  }
  result = '';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>vendors</p>
<input type="radio" name="vendor" value="ve1" />1</br>
<input type="radio" name="vendor" value="ve2" />2</br>
<input type="radio" name="vendor" value="ve3" />3</br>
<p>volume</p>
<input type="radio" name="volume" value="vo1" />1</br>
<input type="radio" name="volume" value="vo2" />2</br>
<input type="radio" name="volume" value="vo3" />3</br>
<p>
  vendors/volume:
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи Стака. Будьте так любезны, поясняйте Минусы к рабочим ответам. Если вам нечего сказать - не ставьте минусы.